# Router cannot see the Ubuntu server VirtualBox on Windows 8

Tags: wireless, server, virtualbox, windows-8, router

I have a Windows 8 os on my computer with a VirtualBox Ubuntu server 14.

- Windows has access to the Internet and is visible on the router as an attached device 10.0.0.x.
- The Ubuntu server has access to the Internet but is not visible on the router, and when calling ifconfig I see: 10.0.2.15

Every time I restart the vm, it gets a different IP, and I would like it to be const.

Where do I start?

===========================================================

So they have mark this as duplicate and I cannot answer with a solution, but here goes...

The main issue was the VirtualBox adding a default Network adapter of type **NAT**

I'm not sure what it the purpose of it, but once I've set the type to **BridgeAdapter** my VM got a proper DHCP from the router, and now I can config my router to set a static IP of the VM network card MAC address!

Only weird thing I had to figure out, is that my router does not show the VM MAC address on the attached devices list, instead it shows the REAL network card MAC address.

So don't get confused and use the MAC defined in the Network adapter in your VM settings!

Let me know if this helps you too.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that is the case, as the solution suggested there does not work for me... or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The link was written from the point of view of a Linux host with a Linux Client - all those items written as 'server' or 'host' will need to be altered (dramatically) to work with the Window OS.

Comment: So I guess the point of asking a question is to simplify the process of solving it... my main issue is what I need to do on my OS? Router? VM?

Comment: Aye, but it's a pretty broad question covering multiple operating systems and devices.  The simple answer to 'How to I get a constant IP address' would be to do a manual configuration of the eth0 on the client machine.  Since you are on a DHCP network, the server may decide to give that address to another device at some point in the future.  So then you need to determine how to change the behaviour of the DHCP machine...

Comment: I was under the impression that a router provides and decide the NAT ip address!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15633/discussion-between-tacb0ss-and-charles-green).

Comment: Sorry guys, but you are wrong... this question is not a duplicate and not like the other ones, I know since I'm able to solve it, but cannot post an answer now... you're been to hasty jumping to conclusions...